# VB, excel macro pause and resume working if possible

Tags: vba, excel

I cannot figure out the best way to do the following problem. Basically my macro (excel, VB) is checking several (100+) worksheets for correct values, if wrong value is found, I want it to stop, give me a warning, then I could have a look into the reason why the value is wrong, correct it manually and then I want to resume the macro, or remember the last value checked so if I return, it remembers where to continue (resume).

My current problem is that it finds the wrong value, then I can either make it stop so I check the problem, or it goes through all the sheets and then I have to remember which sheets had the wrong value.

What I thought of is make a list where the name of sheet is added every time a wrong value is found. The problem is that usually there is more than 1 wrong value in the same sheet if there is a wrong value at all and this added the same sheet name several times to the list. Another problem with that is that I cannot correct the values straight away.

I'm very inexperienced with programming and so would appreciate your idea on how to best approach this problem (I don't want to spend a long time on coding something which wouldn't be efficient for such a "simple" problem).

Comment: you could highlight the errors in the sheet in an *errors* column and handle them at the end with a another macro using David's suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

When the error is found (I'm assuming you've already been able to identify this), you can use the `Application.InputBox` function to prompt you for a new value.

For example, if `rng` is a Range variable that represents the *cell* being checked, and you have some logic to determine where the error happens, then you can just do:

```
rng.Value = Application.InputBox("Please update the value in " & rng.Address, "Error!", rng.Value)
```

The inputbox function effectively halts execution of the procedure, while waiting for input from the user.

If InputBox isn't robust enough, then you can create a custom UserForm to do the same sort of thing. But for modifying single range values, one at a time, the InputBox is probably the easiest to implement.

Comment: If ever there was a more apt use of Inputbox :-)

Comment: I see. For my case simply inputting a value might not be enough. When I manually add/change the values, I need to check several sheets to make sure I don't add a nonsense and hence "pausing and resuming" the whole macro would be a much more comfortable solution for me. However, I had no idea about InputBox and will know to use it in future if a more suitable problem arises ^_^! Thanks!

Comment: It may actually be best to simply print a list of the cells containing errors. Then, you can check and revise them all once the procedure is done, and re-run the macro once you've made all revisions.  That would be an entirely different question though.

Comment: I agree. Over engineering a simple problem is not worth the trade off. @DavidZemens solution is the least headache inducing logic that you can put to maintain the sanity of your data.

Comment: What would be the easiest way to make a list of the worksheets containing error (once in worksheet, I can spot the error straight away)? The problem is that it goes "cell by cell" in a worksheet and as I said in the main post, if there is 1 wrong value, the whole sheet is prone to have more wrong values. Hence if I simply make a list to add name of the worksheet to some array of strings, I will get a long list of repetitive names (ie. 20x sheet(5), 14x sheet(234)...). Is there a way to add to an array/list only if the string is unique in an elegant way?

Comment: I mean I could add a loop to check if it is there already... but I already have 3 nested loops and so the run-time of this macro is already mediocre at best. Maybe simply add them all and then delete the duplicates from the array? How would one go about this? What do you think would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Your follow-up sounds like it ought to be a new question. And one that will probably not be answered unless you show your current code. Questions asking for "conceptual" approaches are prone to being closed as "too broad" or "too many possible answers". If you can show what you're working with (**as a new question, not an update to this one**) then you'll be more likely to get a good answer.

Comment: I'm new to this website and programming in general, so thanks for advice David. I will make a new question where I will show all the important parts of code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can handle this task by using one or two static local variables in your macro.  A variable declared with "static" rather than "dim" will remember its value from the last time that procedure was run.  This can hold where you left off so you can resume from there.

One thing that could be a problem with this solution would be if the macro gets recompiled.  That would probably cause VBA to clear the value that the static variable was holding.  Just doing a data edit in Excel should not cause a recompile, but you will want to watch for this case, just to make sure it doesn't come up.  It almost certainly will if you edit any code between executions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a public variable that stores the cell address of the last checked cell and use a conditional statement to see if it's "mid-macro" for want of a better phrase. here is a very crude example...

```
Public lastCellChecked As String

Sub Check_Someting()

Dim cell As     Excel.Range
Dim WS As       Excel.Worksheet

If Not lastCellChecked = vbNullString Then Set cell = Evaluate(lastCellChecked)

'// Rest of code...

'// Some loop here I'm assuming...
lastCellChecked = "'" & WS.Name & "'!" & cell.Address
If cell.Value > 10 Then Exit Sub '// Lets assume this is classed as an error
'// Rest of loop here...

lastCellChecked = vbNullString
End Sub
```

Comment: But how would the user be able to fix the error whilst the code is running?

Comment: I think OP will also need to store the worksheet name.

Comment: To make sure I understand the logic here: 1. check if there is a starting position (last cell checked) 2. if not, start it from beginning. if yes, start it from where it was interrupted. 3. if interrupted during run-time, store the cell address for next run. I believe I understood correctly and this is, indeed, a much more elegant solution than I would have come up with. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If there is a wrong value I can go into an if statement, where I save the cell.address then throw an error. This can be used to correct the values manually and then contiue macro once again (answering to Pankaj Jaju) I believe.

Comment: @DavidZemens edited to include qualifying address with `Evaluate()` method

Comment: Yes, but now he has to abort the procedure with an `Exit Sub` statement, and then when he restarts the procedure it needs to begin at that range on that worksheet.  There may be other variables (potentially *many* other variables) that would need to be stored and retrieved in a similar way. It's viable, but overcomplicated IMO :)

Comment: @emihir0 David's solution is much cleaner than mine, but you have folloed my logic correctly, yes.

Comment: @DavidZemens agreed, I did initally think `Application.InputBox()` but wasn't sure if it was non-modal to allow the user to amend values during the code execution. Looks like I've also learned something new today! :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create a userform and as mentioned by prior users create a public variable.  When the program finds an error store the cell and initiate the userform.  Your code will stop on the userform.  When you're done checking the problem have a button on the userform that you can click to continue checking.  Your loop can be something like the below.

```
public y as integer

sub temp1 ()       
  rw1= range("a500000").end(xlup).row  'any method to create a range will do
  if y = null then y=1

  for x = y to rw1
      cells(x,1).select 
      'check for the problem your looking for
      if errorX=true then
         userform1.show
         y = activecell.row
         exit sub
      end if
  next x
end sub
```

Comment: `y` will never be `null` in this context. an uninitialized integer will evaluate to `0`.

Comment: but can the user amend values whilst the userform is being shown?

Comment: Yes.  You just need to set the userform to showmodel=true.  Thank you David y should =0 not null.

Answer (score 0):

What about inserting a button (on the sheet or in a menubar) for stopping?

Insert the code below:

```
'This at the top of the module
Public mStop As Boolean

'This in the module
Sub MyBreak()
mStop = True
End Sub

'This is your macro
Sub YourMacro()
'This at the top of your code
mStop = False
'Your code
'...
    'This code where you want to break
    DoEvents '<<<< This makes possible the stop
    If mStop Then
        mCont = MsgBox("Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo)
        If mCont = vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            mStop = False
        End If
    End If
'Your code
'...
End Sub
```

Now you need to create a button and link it to the macro called "MyBreak".